# RegExp for Overiding font color and size

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace which will replace font color value to `#000000` and `size=11`

```
<font color="#1f497d" face="Calibri" size="3">
<font color="#000000"  size="11">

String str=str.replaceall("font color="SOMETHING", "font color="BLACK")
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser for that

Comment: what is your question, please provide input and output.

Comment: My html page is dynamically created based on user inputs which is having different fonts sizes and colors, I would like to override and change these font color to Black and size to 11

Comment: @frhd That is not a joke. For modification of html OP should use a lib wich can modify it and not regex.

Answer (score 1):

use regex:

```
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("size=\".*\"", "size=\"11\"").replaceAll("\"#.{6}\" ", "\"#000000\" "))
```